# How to use vlookup feature in pandas to compute this?

Tags: python, pandas

Well, I have one dataframe(main-df) in pandas where I have trading signals and datetime as my index.
I have 20 more excel files from where I need to find the respective datetime and get the closing price in the main-df.
How do I go to each and every excel file and check if the datetime matches and then return the closing price.

Comment: I'd probably start with `pd.merge()` but try to combine the different Excel files before e.g. by putting them into a database.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

excels = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='your_sheet') for f in 
                       Path(r'dir/to/excels').glob('*.xlsx')]
# concat df.
df = pd.concat(excels)
# clean df.
# merge main_df
merged_df = pd.merge(df,main_df,on='date_time_column',how='inner')
#or if common date time is in index. 
merge_df = pd.merge(df,main_df,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='inner')
```

or we can we use `isin`

```
dates_ = main_df['datetime_col'].tolist()
df_new = df.loc[df['datetime_col'].isin(dates_)]
```